# Android service freezing on MIUI

Tags: android, service, freeze

I am developing a tracking Android application and it's very important for me to keep GPS service in sleep mode.

When I start my app on XRN3 with MIUI 7.2 based on Android 5.0.2 and block device after a while the service is paused. The problem is that onDestroy not called and service resumed only when I send new Intent to my service.

How do I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

onDestroy is not guaranteed to be called. 
Most of time, its called if system decides to shut down your application.

You should use onPause instead.

Comment: The problem is that the app does not shuts down, because all information is saved. And after sending new Intent to my service it doesn't call onCreate.